# What is the deal with keeping all the images on http://sstatic.net

Tags: discussion, images, licensing, legal

For example, the  arrow image is stored here: http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-arrow-up.png . I wonder why not keep everything on local servers.  What is the licensing aspects of those images? Can they be re-used by another party? is the license the same as for the content on SO sites?

Comment: belongs on SO?

Comment: What is so "Programming" about this question to justify posting it on SO?

Comment: It's explained at http://sstatic.net/ ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> We registered the domain sstatic.net
> for this purpose a month ago, and I’m
> pleased to announce that all the
> static resources for the Stack
> Overflow family of websites are now
> hosted at sstatic.net. This domain is
> of course cookieless and optimized for
> serving static content with the lowest
> possible overhead (and, as before, a
> far-future expires header, so zero
> requests are made to the server for
> cached static elements).

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/

Answer (score 7):

Since a lot of the images are the same between sites, having them all served from one domain allows the browser to cache them so that it doesn't have to get a copy from each site. It also helps take some of the load off the main servers by setting up a dedicated server for static content.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/

Comment: I should have thought to copy and paste part of the article instead of trying to write my own answer. I'll get you next time Gadget - er, TheTXI!

Comment: Go Go Gadget Pony

Answer (score 2):

I believe it all still falls under the same copyright rules as the rest of the site.

site design and logo is © 2009 stackoverflow.com llc

Answer (score 1):

Static items are stored on sstatic.net to provide a better caching mechanism, reducing bandwidth consumption from the main sites.  The rights to the images remain with SO.